# Getting Error as "object is not an instance of declaring class"

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

I am getting the issue on below line:

```
java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {XMLRequest});
```

XMLRequest coming as

```
"XMLRequest": com.webservices.MaintenanceRequest@1b834def"
```

When i trying to call a service from my soap client and getting error while executing the above line and find the error as below:

```
2018-05-17 11:18:59.703 ERROR 7104 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.a.e.s.BeanSerializer                 : Exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor.get(BeanPropertyDescriptor.java:127) ~[axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:192) [axis-1.4.jar:?]
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializationContext.serializeActual(SerializationContext.java:1504) [axis-1.4.jar:?]
```

Can anyone please suggest on this.

Comment: got any solution?